# react app with express.js route setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I was using angular.js and I do this in express.js

```
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl)
})
```

so that the browser will use the route of angular instead of express. But how to do that with react router? I have 2 folder, named server and client, server folder has express and api logic while client folder simply a react app.

Comment: why you use * in your express route!?  what is the name of your other API?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to serve the front end static files like js/html with express?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the path in of the HTML file you are rendering your app to

```
app.get("/",(res,res) => {
res.sendFile('put the path of the html file you are rendering your app into here');
}
```

here is an example of a express server.js that works with react

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
});


app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port: " +  PORT);
});
```